# Prove that a matrix that is nonsingular and nonnegative definite is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

The key point is to prove: when $A$ is nonsingular, there will not be any $\mathbf{x}$ such that $\mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{x} = 0$.

Comment: As the answer below. I believe this matrix $A$ should be symmetric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For symmetric A it is true because A$\geq 0$ means that all eigen values of A are non negative and since A is given non-singular so $0$ is not an eigen value of A, hence all eigen values of A becomes positive so A becomes positive. If you are taking the field $C$ then your statement is true because in $C$ every positive definite matrix is hermitian but not in the case of real $R$.

Comment: Yes. I understand. Thanks for your elegant proof.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. Take $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $\mathbf{x}=(1,1)$. Or are you assuming, as in the title of the question, that $A$ is nonnegative definite?

Comment: This matrix is not nonnegative definite = positive semidefinite. One eigenvalue is negative.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is false if you are working in a real vector space. Take $A$ to be the matrix that rotates vectors a quarter turn clockwise in the 2D plane:

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} .$$

This matrix is nonsingular but corresponds to the $0$ quadratic form. Do you mean for $A$ to be symmetric?

Comment: Yeah. $A$ should be symmetric. Thanks for your counterexample.